# Why won't toggle hide on second click?

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I am playing around with jQuery and built a little nav, but I can't seem to get it to close. It seems to work in 1.12.4, but not 3.1.0?

Javascript:

```
//open and close navigation
var navOpen = function(){
$('.navToggle').click(function(){
    $('.nav').toggle();
    console.log("i have been clicked");
});
//on hover, show description of icon    
$('.navImg1').hover(function(){
    $('.navHover1').slideToggle(100);
});

$('.navImg2').hover(function(){
    $('.navHover2').slideToggle(100);
});

$('.navImg3').hover(function(){
    $('.navHover3').slideToggle(100);
});

$('.navImg4').hover(function(){
    $('.navHover4').slideToggle(100);
});

$('.navImg5').hover(function(){
    $('.navHover5').slideToggle(100);
});

};
//hide all when document loads
$('.navHover1').hide();
$('.navHover2').hide();
$('.navHover3').hide();
$('.navHover4').hide();
$('.navHover5').hide();
$('.nav').hide();
$(document).ready(navOpen);
```

I have just started looking at jQuery, so if any of this is nonsense, I am really sorry!

Cheers!

EDIT: sorry, of course you need my HTML!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Photoshop template site</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" 
    rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
    <div class="navHolder">
    <div class="navbar">
        <img class="navToggle" src="menu-icon.png">
        <ul class="nav">
            <img src="home-icon.png" class="navImg1">
                <li class="navHover1">Home</li>
            <img src="about-icon.png" class="navImg2">
                <li class="navHover2">About</li>
            <img src="photo-icon.png" class="navImg3">
                <li class="navHover3">Photos</li>
            <img src="website-icon.png" class="navImg4">
                <li class="navHover4">Website</li>
            <img src="contact-icon.png" class="navImg5">
                <li class="navHover5">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </header>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML would help.

Comment: This is all basic jQuery functionality and will work in both versions.

Comment: It´s working v 3.1.0  https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/j0khu4ur/

Comment: Tested it working too... but @CMedina posted his Fiddle first. So there must be something else if it doesn't work for you... Any console error ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette no console errors, doesn't seem to work with either 1.12.4 or 3.1.0.